# Coloring a textured path to a plane?

Tags: mesh, uv, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-painting

How would I create/color a textured path onto my plane. I want to color a simple path onto my plane, but i just cant seem to be able to do it. I already downloaded a texture image. I tried doing in UV editing and it doesn't seem to work. [image: This is my island]

Comment: Did you already tried what is shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il7ajiCepus? Could you show your UV island?

Comment: if you simply apply a texture, it will be deformed by your mesh, since it's not a plane, as in the suggested video above... is this what you want? Is what you have in mind like a trail way thath climbs a mountain?

Comment: We need to know if you are using an image texture already to hold your paint - from the screenshot, all I can tell is you are using a green material and that doesn't mean you can paint on anything. You need an image texture to paint on, and you can use it as a black and white stencil between two image textures for creating grass and path, etc. or you can paint directly to one image as your colormap.